# Tailwindcss: How to focus-within and focus-visible at the same time

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want to focus a `div` surrounding a button but only when keyboard focused. Usually `focus-within` works, but in this case it should only focus on keyboard focus (`focus-visible:`) and not when clicking with the mouse(`focus:`).

Essentially, I need to combine `focus-within` and `focus-visible`. How can this be done?

Tailwind Play: https://play.tailwindcss.com/ApDB5gSjqv

```html
<div class="flex h-screen items-center justify-center">
  <div class="rounded-lg bg-green-100 px-20 py-20 focus-within:ring-4 focus-within:ring-blue-300">
    <button class="bg-green-200 px-6 py-3 focus:outline-none">Focusable Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notes:

- Based on [this thread](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3080), it looks like w3c doesn't have support for `focus-within-visible`. What's an alternative or round-about way to achieve this?
- It looks like there is support for `:has(:focus)` selector in some browsers but how should this be applied in Tailwind...? [Source](https://github.com/WICG/focus-visible/issues/151)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using focus-within you could add `relative` to the div you want to make look focused with the ring. Then make the button a `peer` and have an absolutely positioned div after it use the `peer-focus-visible` modifier to add any "focused" styles you want.

EDIT: You'll need to make the div be behind the button by adding relative to the button and assigning an appropriate z-index value to both the inset div and button.

```
<div class="flex h-screen items-center justify-center">
  <div class="rounded-lg bg-green-100 px-20 py-20 relative">
    <button class="bg-green-200 px-6 py-3 focus:outline-none peer relative z-[1]">Focusable Button</button>
  <div class="absolute inset-0 rounded-lg peer-focus-visible:ring-4 peer-focus-visible:ring-blue-300 z-[0]"></div>
</div>
```

Here is an edited example on Tailwind Play https://play.tailwindcss.com/us5kpJg6cV

Comment: Thanks. It's almost there, but the button can't be clicked anymore cuz the div is on-top of the button...

Comment: Ah, yes, a z-index issue. Updated answer.

Answer (score 10):

You can indeed use `:has` with `:focus-visible` to achieve what you want. Check the browser support on [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/css-has).

Use [arbitrary variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-arbitrary-variants) to build your selector:

```
<div class="[&:has(:focus-visible)]:ring-4">
  <button>Focusable button</button>
</div>
```